# Modify date object in struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, datetime, date, struts2

I have a date object and I just need to add 15 minutes to it. This is not for the sake of display though, the actual object's minutes need to be modified.

When I try modifying it through the `<s:set>` tag, Date is treated like a string. I am not sure if I am suppose to be even using s:set in this case.

I know I should be doing such modifications on the Java side, but I want to test both methods, especially if this date modification is actually simple.

Comment: You should avoid doing business logic in presentation. what's the problem you were facing on action side when you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different method. I used  for an hour and minute variable. The code is mainly in the JSP, and I think it is more efficient this way.

For those wondering, I was generating a Calendar of events. I needed to fill in the time between the events with a certain amount of free time links. I thought creating "empty events" in my event list was inefficient, so I thought doing it on the JSP side was better.